# asp.net, I manage to publish my site, but don't find how to access it

Tags: asp.net, iis

I published a simple ASP.net website referring to this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

I managed to publish my site to C:\testapp as specified, and I shared the folder as specified. Then, this documentation suggests that I should magically be able to access my site via http://localhost/testapp/default.aspx

Doesn't seem to work... What is missing here ?

Comment: have you setup IIS to run the site?  Not sure what environment your running but here's a reference to setup IIS. http://www.no-ip.com/support/guides/web_servers/setting_up_iis.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the walk-through carefully you will notice the following point just after publishing the webpage and before opening your webpage:

> Create an IIS virtual directory that points to the target folder.

So, in order to see the webpage you must have IIS installed and configured to treat your local path as a virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a website in IIS and point it to this location.  Then browse to the site url.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method would be to publish as follows:

```
Publish Method - Web Deploy
Service URL - localhost
Site/Application - Default Web Site/TestApp
```

It should publish your site contents to the below folder unless you configured IIS differently.

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestApp\
```

You should then be able to access it using the URL http://localhost/TestApp/default.aspx

If not, check IIS (`Control Panel -> Administrative Tools - Internet Information Services`) your site should be listed in the tree view

If not, add a `Virtual Directory`

```
Alias : TestApp
Location : C:\TestApp\
```

try access your site again, if you're still having problems, attempt to do an IIS Reset by Typing `iisreset` into `Command Prompt`